# Does express.json() for parsing JSON request body return middleware with synchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Express.js's documentation, especially from [this part](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#dont-use-synchronous-functions), it is advised not to use synchronous functions whenever possible because in high-traffic websites, synchronous calls add up and can reduce application's performance.

I use `--trace-sync-io` in my Express app starting command to trace sync calls in my application, and below is my code snippet:

```
const express = require("express")

const app = express()

app.use(compression())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'ok', result: req.body})
})

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({message: 'ok', result: null})
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'))
```

I believe that if an endpoint needs to parse incoming JSON request body, it needs to use either the built-in request body parser such as the one from Express, but every time I hit my endpoint from Postman, it seems like Node detected that this snippet code is using sync functions, with the stack trace as follows:

```
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:425:12)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:425:12)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:425:12)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:678:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at getCodec (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:46:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at getCodec (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:46:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at getCodec (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at getCodec (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:65:27)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js:127:23)
    at getDecoder (C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:46:18)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:6:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:7:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:8:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:9:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at readSync (node:fs:747:26)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:449:20)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:487:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at closeSync (node:fs:546:11)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:504:8)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:10:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2537:13)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:11:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at realpathSync (node:fs:2579:29)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:477:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:473:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:485:22)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:670:20)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:11:5
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at openSync (node:fs:598:26)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:11:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
(node:21552) WARNING: Detected use of sync API
    at tryStatSync (node:fs:422:25)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:471:17)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at C:\Project\JavaScript\nodejs-playground\node_modules\iconv-lite\encodings\index.js:11:5
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
```

Does `express.json()` return a middleware with sync calls in it? At first I thought this won't cause a problem, because the middleware is only registered once during server start up, but I think the sync API usage is detected every time the endpoint is hit.

Do I need to worry about whether this will affect my application performance or not?

Comment: Trying locally I get 10 warnings for the first call and then 0 for subsequent API calls. Also you're worrying too much about performance, `express.json()` is used in production in high-traffic websites. The warnings come mostly from using `require`, try using ESM and the new import syntax.

If you're that worried about performance, you can try using `bun` instead of `node` to run your code.

Comment: `express.json()` is only required if you intend on sending json data to your backend, which you already know. It is indeed synchronous which blocks the event loop. However, as far as I'm aware there is no async version of *this* middleware and the topic has been brought up a few times in the past [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/132) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2031#issuecomment-114944005).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it will create issues in your application.

When you execute synchronous code in a Node.js application, it can indeed block the event loop, which may cause delays in processing other incoming requests. This can lead to degraded performance, especially in applications with high concurrency.

In the case of express.json(), it's a middleware that synchronously parses incoming JSON payloads in requests. If the JSON payload is large or if the parsing operation takes a significant amount of time, it can block the event loop and delay the processing of other requests.

To mitigate this issue, it's generally recommended to use asynchronous operations whenever possible in Node.js applications. Express itself provides middleware for asynchronous request handling, such as express.urlencoded() and custom middleware functions.

For example, you can use express.urlencoded() for parsing URL-encoded form data asynchronously

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: What makes you assume that the `urlencoded` middleware is doing asynchronous parsing?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).